# Lights out with branch and bound

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm implementing an algorithm using branch and bound to find a solution for the game lights out. I can't find the way to relax the restrictions of the game in order to find the bounds. How can I relax the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. You need to tell us *much* more to have an actionable question. If you have a high-level algorithm question, consider a) is the implementation language actually relevant? (Consider the `language-agnostic` tag instead, especially if you don't have any code to show.) b) Would another site, such as https://cs.stackexchange.com, be more appropriate for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a quick but poor quality lower bound by dividing the number of lights on by five and rounding up -- each press turns off at most five lights.